# How do I return JSON without parent tag on JAX-RS?

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, liferay

I'm trying to create a REST API module for Liferay but I'm facing problems when trying to generate JSON responses from my webservices.

I would like to generate a simple JSON like this:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "News not found for ID: 5"
}
```

But instead, this is what I get:

```
{
    "parentResponse": {
        "status": "ok",
        "message": "News not found for ID: 5"
    }
}
```

Here's my POJO class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ParentResponse {

    public String status, message;
    public Object item;

    public ParentResponse() {

    }

    public ParentResponse(String status, String message, Object item) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.item = item;
    }   
}
```

My webservice which returns the json:

```
// return a single news based on supplied ID
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getNewsById(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        ResponseBuilder builder;
        try {
            News news = findById(new Long(id));
            if (news != null) {
                builder = Response.ok(news);
            } 
            else { // This is my POJO class returned as a JSON
                ParentResponse parentResponse = new ParentResponse("ok", "News not found for ID: " + id, null);

                builder = Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity(parentResponse);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
```

So, how do I get the JSON without the root tag? I tried adding the (name="") next to the @XmlRootElement annotation, but that didn't work.

Comment: What you don't try to use jackson for marshalling your beans ?

Comment: How do I add that to my project's build.gradle file? I tried to add this: compileInclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core'

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Try to add the lines below in the module's build.gradle: 

```compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.9.0" compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0"```

Comment: Thanks @javaxiss that seems to work. But now, what do I do with this?

Comment: You should use `@JsonProperty` on your model attributes (ParentResponse) like the following:

`@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class ParentResponse {
    @JsonProperty("message")
    public String message;
   @JsonProperty("status")
    public String status;
    ...
}`

Comment: That's giving me a 500 internal server error which returns this:

No message body writer has been found for class ParentResponse, ContentType: application/json

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use jackson provider for marshalling/unmarshalling the json input/output (s)  (as I did in my comments  to your post):

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.9.0" 
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0"
```

Your model should be like the following:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) 
public class ParentResponse { 

  @JsonProperty("message") 
  public String message; 

  @JsonProperty("status") 
  public String status; 

//... 

}
```

If you use Liferay 7, I would suggest also to take advantage of OSGi, by creating a service that calls your service endpoint (`Response getNewsById(@PathParam("id") String id)`). When your OSGi service starts, it should set the jackson provider and sets web service endpoint url ... and anything else to initialize your service in general.

```
@Component(immediate = false)
public class WonderfulOsgiService{

    private MyWebService myWebService;

    public Response getNews( String id) {
        return myWebService.getNewsById(id);
    }


    @Activate
    @Modified
    private void activate(Map<String, Object> config) {
        // Creates jackson provider for marshalling/unmarshalling json
        ObjectMapper myMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        myMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE);
        JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider(myMapper);
        provider.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<>();
        providers.add(provider);


        //web service endpoint address
        String address = "http://my-web-service-address.com/url/"
        //MyWebService is the class containing getNewsById(id)
        myWebService = JAXRSClientFactory.create(address, MyWebService.class, providers);   

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Liferay 7.1 with CXF's Jettison support you can configure it by adding a configuration file to the `/configs` dir:

`org.apache.aries.jax.rs.jaxb.json.cfg`
with contents:

```
drop.collection.wrapper.element=true
drop.root.element=true
serialize.as.array=true
support.unwrapped=true
```

from Liferay 7.2 onwards Liferay ships with Jackson as default JAXB provider.

Please note that the OSGi JAX-RS Whiteboard support in Liferay allows you to switch JSON providers without having to change the code of your application. You can find the different integrations in https://github.com/apache/aries-jax-rs-whiteboard/tree/master/integrations

or how to provide the jackson support in Liferay (if not in 7.2, which is included) with the dependencies here: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.2.x/modules/apps/portal-remote/portal-remote-jaxrs-whiteboard-jaxb-json/build.gradle

just make sure to replace the CXF jettison ones, which might have side effects on other bundles which depend on it.